# Function to draw random image from specified category destroys site logic - why?

Tags: functions

**I'm trying to create a function in my child theme's functions.php file that will draw a linked image on every page.**  The link has to have a class, and the image must also have a class.

**The image is to be a random selection from a specific category**, specified by that category's ID.  It should also have dimensions of 240px x 160px.

I've cobbled this function together, which **works without error if I just call the function in a standalone fashion, using a test PHP page**.  However if I place this function in my child theme's functions.php and hook it into my child theme's header.php file, the site's logic just gets completely destroyed: clicking on a link to a post never gets there, and all sorts of things go wrong.

The moment I remove the function from my child theme's functions.php file, everything in the site is back to normal, so it must be doing something drastically wrong whilst resident in the child theme's functions.php file.  I just wish I could see what that is!

Here's the function ("boxify" is the class for the image link, and "top-right-image" is the class for the image):

```
function draw_image() {
$catg = '13';
$posts=query_posts('showposts=1&cat='.$catg);
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
if ( $images = get_children(array(
'post_parent' => 0,
'numberposts' => 1,
'orderby' => 'rand',
'post_mime_type' => 'image',)))
{
foreach( $images as $image ) {
$attachmenturl=wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID);
$attachmentimage=wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, array(240,160), 0, 'class=top-right-image' );
echo '<a class="boxify" href="'.$attachmenturl.'">'.$attachmentimage.'</a>';
}
} else {
echo '<img class="top-right-image" src="'.child_template_directory.'/images/default.jpg" />';
}
}
}
add_action('do_draw_image', 'draw_image');
```

In my child theme's header.php file, I use:

```
do_action('do_draw_image');
```

Why does this function work as expected 'on its own' but destroy the WP logic when placed in the child theme's functions.php file?  What have I missed?

Comment: [never use `query_posts`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Comment: OMG - I just changed `query_posts` to `get_posts` and everything seems to be working OK.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Now all I need to do is to filter out portrait orientation images and only accept landscape orientation ones - but I guess that's another question.  Thank you so much again !